Can I select and bevel the top edge of the letters in this model?
I spent several hours retopologizing the letters for this model, and then doing a Boolean Difference extrusion onto a block.

However now the top edge of the letters is creating a weird geometry and I am unable how to select it to make it beveled.

How can I do this?

Object Data Properties > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data and no you cannot because of the poor topology.

Ah thanks this is great and solved the weird geometry issue, but now I'm trying to select the edge to bevel it and it's proving harder than I thought

you need to retopologize it like this: https://snipboard.io/ISPpgQ.jpg . have you tried Quadriflow Remesh? the screenshot is using the paid addon Quad Remesher. then you can smooth the vertices with Ctrl+V > Smooth Vertices

@HarryMcKenzie ah thanks... unfortunately I'm getting paid a quarter of the price of this addon for this job so it's not immediately worth it to get it :/

can you provide the blend file with the rectangular border being sharp edges? it's better to have it sharp before the remesh

@HarryMcKenzie ok I just did

@MicroMachine sorry the mesh is too complicated I don't think you can do a bevel on it. the letter outlines have angles that are too sharp to allow it due to the pointed parts of the K and the N letters and the density is too high at those parts

I have simplified your mesh here https://blend-exchange.com/b/qSw24rEl. And all that had to be done was just to inset the mesh but unfortunately as you can see here in this screenshot it's not possible due to the pointed nature of the K and the N letters. If you can adjust to reduce the density on those parts then you could successfully inset and then bevel the edges. You could inset and then manually fix the mesh at those parts. then you can bevel

@HarryMcKenzie Thank you so much! I ended up using the free demo of Quad Remesher and will be keeping an eye out for free remeshing tools until Blender's own becomes decent

You could redo the topology this way:
Select the faces facing upwards with ShiftG (Select Similar) > Normal:

Only keep the top faces, press X > Limited Dissolve to simplify and separate the mesh as a new object:

Fill the letters (F or AltF):

Extrude the mesh twice to get this:

Now you can bevel, it will need some re-rework though as the bevel faces will overlap on some parts:

